# Can I render content dynamically within an iPhone app according to the referrer to my app in iTune appstore

Tags: iphone, referrer

I have an app that I need to render different content depending on which site refers the user to download my app.  For example, website A has a link to let its users to download my app, I would like to display some products from website A when user first runs my app after installation.  Is this doable?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely doable, the easiest way I can think of would be to have the user enter some kind of promo code corresponding to the website they downloaded your app from. From there you can compare what they entered to an array of valid promo code strings and if it matches set a bool for that particular promo code to YES, then set up your UI to something like

`if(website1bool == YES){Display customized UI};`

Then add this bool to `NSUserDefaults` to remember the changes. It might end up being a lot of "ifs" but it's definitely doable!

**EDIT**: in defaults set up would be more or less...

```
if([myDefaults boolForKey@"website1Bool"] == YES){Configure};
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without user input? Thanks.